# Password hashing with bcrypt

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, hash, sequelize.js

Guys I'm trying to make a password hash with BCRYPT, but the user real password is sent to PostgresSQL
what can I do to fix it? Did I write it wrong?

```
import { Model, Sequelize } from 'sequelize';

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

class User extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init(
      {
        name: Sequelize.STRING,
        email: Sequelize.STRING,
        password: Sequelize.VIRTUAL,
        password_hash: Sequelize.STRING,
        provider: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
      },
      {
        sequelize,
      }
    );

    this.addHook('beforeSave', async (user) => {
      if (user.password) {
        user.password_hash = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 8);
      }
      return this;
    });
  }
}

export default User;
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 password fields in your users table? Delete "password" then you'll have only the "password_hash".

Comment: The "password" I'll be created by the user, and "password_hash" I'll be created based on the user "password", that's why I'm using bcrypt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment,

I think you didn't understand how bcrypt works.

To register a user you do

```
await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 8)
```

This will generate you the hashed version of the user's password.

Now save that in the database (call it whatever you want, password/hashed_password)

You only need the hashed version in the database. bcrypt knows how to verify whether or not a raw string is equals to a hashed string.

Therefore when you do your login code you'll need to call

```
await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, db.password, (err, same) => {
 if(err) res.sendStatus(500)

 if(same){
  res.send("LOGIN SUCCSESSFULL!")
 }else{
  res.send("WRONG USERNAME/PASSWORD!")
 }
})
```

I just wrote this from the top of my head but it should work.

Comment: That was the problem, the hashed version was not saved on the database but it was my mistake when the user was created he already created the hashed version, 
instead of your own password, like
"password_hash": "000" instead of "password": "000 
And reading your answer I realize my mistake.